# Are biometrics needed to renew Schengen tourist visa from UK for Indian?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens

I am in the UK on a Tier 2 visa. I applied for a Schengen visa last year, which is expiring in March 2019, via the German embassy. I am now considering to apply for a new one via the French embassy.

Do I have to go for biometrics to be taken in order to get another Schengen visa or can I do it by mail?

Answer (score 1):

New biometrics are not necessary if the previous ones are less than [five years](http://eeas.europa.eu/archives/delegations/india/documents/travel_eu/changes-in-schengen-visa-application-process-india_en.pdf) old, unless the consulate has doubts as to your identity/data.

Comment: so can i apply for france visa via mail and do not go to france consulate ? i tried finding it on tslconnect but no information :(

Comment: @KrunalBarot, look at field 27 of the application form. If you check "yes," they *can* ask you to come in person, but they rarely do that.

Comment: Still in the end it shows below stuff,What next?
1. On the day of your appointment, you must bring the following documents :
> Printed application form(s)  Print
> Receipt(s) and supporting documents.  Print
2. Payment / Biometrics
> You must pay the relevant visa application fee and service charge, if applicable.

> Your biometric data will be collected (if necessary).

3. Your visa center
You can contact :

> TLScontact of London

Comment: like the main line    2. Payment / Biometrics
> You must pay the relevant visa application fee and service charge, if applicable.

> Your biometric data will be collected (if necessary).

Comment: it seems the appointment has to be done physically ?