# Personal interview requirement for obtaining visa

Tags: visas, schengen, applications

My biometric details were submitted in December 2018 for visa to Belgium. Now I want a visa for Switzerland. Whether I will have to appear for biometric again ?

Comment: Not according to https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-information-system_en but someone with better knowledge may confirm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are biometrics needed to renew Schengen tourist visa from UK for Indian?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133068/are-biometrics-needed-to-renew-schengen-tourist-visa-from-uk-for-indian)

Answer (score 2):

If you are applying for a Schengen short-visit visa (type C) again, you **do not** need to provide the biometric information again if you have provided fingerprints for another Schengen type C visa application that was made during the last 59 months.

> A person applies for a visa for the first time on February 9, 20XX.
>
> On June 25, 20XX+4 (52 months after the first application), they apply for a new visa: their fingerprints are copied from the first application.
>
> On September 15, 20XX+4 (67 months after the first application), they submit a new visa application: their fingerprints are taken again.
>
> p. 71, [Swiss SEM Visa Manual (in French)](https://www.sem.admin.ch/dam/sem/fr/data/rechtsgrundlagen/weisungen/visa/bfm/vhb1-version-bfm-f.pdf)

You may still be required to attend an appointment if the data previously collected is deemed insufficient due to quality reasons (rarely happens, but possible).

If your biometrics were previously collected for residence permits or type D visas by national authorities, you may need to make an appointment to provide biometrics again for a short-term visa.

Switzerland does not usually require biometric information for a national visa. Your fingerprints will be collected after your arrival in Switzerland.

In any case, even if a new biometric collection is not needed, a personal interview might be required at a later stage depending on your personal circumstances.

The exact procedure you need to follow will be found on [the website of the Swiss embassy in your country of residence](https://www.eda.admin.ch/eda/en/fdfa/entry-switzerland-residence.html).

Answer (score -2):

Yes

They're two complete separate countries with different immigration authorities who will want to check if you are who you say you are when they issue your visa

Comment: Biometrics are collected mostly to facilitate enforcement after the visa is issued (i.e. check that the person who presents themselves to the border really is the one who went through the process and prevent multiple people from using the same visa). Consequently “checking you are who you say you are” isn't the primary goal of this procedure and can still be done at the border.

Comment: In fact, the first time around, there is no reference database against which you could check this data. The data encoded in the visa becomes the reference and the check happens at the border. In all fraud scenarios I can think of, you do *not* want the prior data to be reused because that would increase the risk of being found out at the border. The data is of course shared between Belgium, Switzerland, and all other Schengen countries through the VIS (that's also how enforcement is supposed to work).

Comment: Switzerland and Belgium are both part of the Schengen area.  Therefore, the statement "with different immigration authorities," which is true, does not tell the whole story.  They have different immigration authorities, but they participate in a common immigration control system.